# Change foreground/background color of Item in Listbox programmatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, list, colors

How can i add different items with either background/foreground color different in WPF listbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can can create a DataTemplete, set it to ListBox.ItemTemplate and use DataTrigger to change the display of the items.

ListBox has some very annoying behaviors that make styling it using data template difficult - in this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox) you will find the list of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an AlternationCount property, [more info provided by this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx)

Or you can add to your objs binded to a listbox Background and Foreground properties and bind them in a DataTemplate of ListBox.ItemTemplate and change them in code however you like, properties must update themselves on every changing.

Answer (score -1):

After tearing my hair out with this one (and your particular usecase might differ from mine) I found the [WPF Toolkit's](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx) DataGrid cured all my needs.